# Nodejs www mac os x server

Tags: macos, apache, node.js, dns, osx-server

I'm trying to get node.js to work on a mac os x server. Using the server app, here I've set example.com to listen to all ip's on port 80 and read from a folder, example.com has an A record pointing to my static ip for the server. This works fine for apache.

I've set node.js to listen to port 8080 on my local ip, but when I go to example.com:8080 I get 404.

```
}).listen(8080, '10.100.100.15');
```

Apache is also listening on that ip, but only on port 80 as far as I know. 
Any thoughts, links and such appreciated.

Comment: You need to post more code, specifically what routes node.js is listening on. Without any routes, it will respond with 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router was missing a forwarder for 8080.